# Firebug Profile

Tags: firebug, profiler

Can firebug profile work over HTTPS?
I have used it over HTTP and it works but when I try it on HTTPS there is no details displayed i.e functions called, time taken etc.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

firebug *can* profile over HTTPS, just tried and saw it working. however, there seem to be issues that some sites and some versions work and some don't. the firebug [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/search?group=firebug&q=profiler) and [project page](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list) might be good places for additional info.